# What is the relationship between Kant's idea of the "transcendental grounds of experience" and his " transcendental theory of cognition"

Tags: epistemology, kant

So I understand the former as simply being what must be the case for experience to be possible (the a priori forms), yet I am not so sure of the latter. Does it simply mean that an object always has reference to a subject?

Comment: Can you clarify or describe what's really *transcendental* in Kant's transcendental idealism/grounds/theory?...

Comment: by transcendental= "of the mind"; a priori, not derived via experience.

Comment: But if transcendental simply means "of the mind", then shouldn't all metaphysics of the mind (almost all idealism, almost all phenomenology including Husserl's transcendental one of course) be called *transcendental*?...